# Setting choices for a field in a Form Wizard?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am trying to make a simple quiz app. I am trying to use Form Wizard but I don't see anything in the docs about setting the choices for a form field. I would also like to use the same form field multiple times.

## models.py

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice

#create a multiple choice quiz to start
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice)
    module = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

## views.py

```
class QuizWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return render_to_response('done.html', {
            'form_data':[form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^answer/(?P<question_id>\d+)', 'quiz.views.answer_question', name='answer_question'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the same concept for form fields as model fields when it comes to choices. [Here is the reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-choices) for model fields.

Unless you plan to add many choices, you shouldn't have a table just for that. You could alter your model:

```
CHOICES = ((1,'One'),(2,'Two'))

class Question(models.Model):
    choices = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES)
```

If you structure it like above, then a `ModelForm` will do what you expect and render a drop down with the right choices for the `choices` field.

As for field reuse, django's built-in form fields are designed just for that. You can also create your own [custom form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#creating-custom-fields) if the built-ins don't suit you and reuse them.

If you are creating forms for models, have a read through the [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) documentation.  `ModelForm`s are like regular forms but a lot of the work is taken care of - like rendering fields that match your models, input validation, saving of new records, etc.

--

> I know how to set choices for a field, but when I am using a Form
>   Wizard and passing in the form, I don't know how to set the choices
>   for a field. I can't set the choices in the form because it changes
>   for every question, and I am using the same form for every question

If you want to set the choices for a form, from an *instance of a model*, then you need to first fetch the instance, then pass it to the form class:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question

question_form = QuestionForm() # empty form
a_question = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
another_form = QuestionForm(instance=a_question) # "prefilled" form
```

Now `another_form` will have values filled in from the `a_question` instance.

Comment: I know how to set choices for a field, but when I am using a Form Wizard and passing in the form, I don't know how to set the choices for a field. I can't set the choices in the form because it changes for every question, and I am using the same form for every question....